# Comparing sub strings after using split() function

Tags: javascript

I'm using [socket.io](/questions/tagged/socket.io)to send some data `msg` to the front-end in the format of `data1 : data2`. I'm then using Javascript function `msg.split(":")` to split this data and `alert` a message if `data2` is equal to a string.

The problem is that for no reason, in spite of the data that has been split being of type `String`, the `==` or `===` operators don't work and the `if` statement shown below is never entered.

Here is the [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)code:

```
socket.on('alldata', function(msg) {
  var [data1, data2] = msg.split(":");
  console.log(data2 + "," + typeof(data2) + "," + data2.length); //here it logs "SE,String,2"

  if (data2 == "SE") { // is the direction of the wind South East
    alert("entered if statement");
  }
});
```

I tried single quotes instead of double quotes, but i still face the same error.

For debugging purposes as an input `data2` is always `SE` without spaces, `data1` is a number but it's not important as i'm only using `data2`, so what i'm expecting to happen is that the `if` condition to evaluate to true and eventually `alert` the message inside.

Comment: are you using jQuery, Try to trim it jQuery.trim(data2 )

Comment: Is that really the code you're using ? Or did you rewrite part of it for the question ? Please also paste the *exact* result of the console.log (`typeof` can't return `"String"` and you don't seem to take into account the spaces you added in your "format" sentence).

Comment: Please provide inputs and expected outputs.

Comment: @JPRLCol i did that, i didn't work

Comment: @DenysSéguret this is the actual log from the console

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan the data comes to the front-end in the format `WindSpeed:Wind_Direction` , in the case of the wind direction it's always `SE` for the sake of the debugging

Comment: @Moutasem There's no way you can get `"String"` from a `typeof`. See http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.3

Comment: @Moutasem try if(data2.trim() == "SE")

Comment: @DenysSéguret could explain why is that please?

Comment: [edit] your question with the data you are using for testing this code, what you're expecting to happen, and what actually happens. See [mcve].

Comment: @JPRLCol i did that and got an error in the console saying 'trim() is not a function'

Comment: @Moutasem try if((""+data2).trim() == "SE")

Comment: @JPRLCol could you explain why you added the double quotations before the `date2`

Comment: @Moutasem is to treat all as a string

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan edited thanks for notifying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- 1st - works as expected
- 2nd - does not work because of extra spaces
  (not visible in console log)
- 3rd - works after trimming

```js
        // 1
        var msg = "Left:Right";
        var [data1 , data2] = msg.split(":");
        console.log(data2 + "," + typeof(data2) + "," + data2.length); 

        if(data2 == "Right"){ 
            console.log("entered if statement");
        }
        
        // 2
        var msg = " Left : Right ";
        var [data1 , data2] = msg.split(":");
        console.log(data2 + "," + typeof(data2) + "," + data2.length); 

        if(data2 == "Right"){ // 
            console.log("entered if statement");
        }
        
        // 3
        var msg = " Left : Right ";
        var [data1 , data2] = msg.split(":");
        console.log(data2 + "," + typeof(data2) + "," + data2.length); 

        if(data2.trim() == "Right"){ 
            console.log("entered if statement");
        }
```